# Call a default image wih f:media file

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to change the call of a dynamic image to a static default image, so I changed :

```
<f:media file="{mediaElement}" />
```

with :

```
<f:media file="{f:uri.image(src: 'paht_to_my_default_image\', treatIdAsReference:1}" />
```

but i get an error :

```
Argument 1 passed to TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\Rendering\RendererRegistry::getRenderer() must implement interface TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\FileInterface, string given, called in /var/www/src/typo3_src-7.6.32/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/MediaViewHelper.php on line 90
```

I do not know if I have a syntax error.

Comment: Not really an answer, but using <f:image> instead is not an option for you? <f:image src="path-to-file" alt="" />

Comment: Any reason to not simply use a normal <img> tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem, the problem was at the syntax level.

This code below works perfectly :

```
<f:image src="EXT:myext/Resources/typo3_logo.png" 
class="img-responsive lazyload" 
title="{mediaElement.originalResource.title}" 
alt="{mediaElement.originalResource.alternative}" 
data="{src: '{f:uri.image(image:mediaElement,
width: settings.list.media.image.width, 
height: settings.list.media.image.height, 
maxWidth: settings.list.media.image.maxWidth, 
maxHeight: settings.list.media.image.maxHeight)}'}" 
width="{f:if(condition: settings.list.media.image.width, then: 
settings.list.media.image.width, else: settings.media.width)}" 
height="{f:if(condition: settings.list.media.image.height, then: 
settings.list.media.image.height, else: settings.media.height)}"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the file attribute it expects a uid of a file in the filelist. You could use the f:image viewhelper and give it a src attribute:

`<f:image src="path_to_my_default_image" />`

Comment: Thanks, I used f:image but the output don't show the src :
     
    <f:image src="path_dafault_img" class="lazyload" data="{src: '{f:uri.image(image: mediaElement)}'}"/>

HTML Output : 

    <img data-src="/fileadmin/user_upload/original.png" class="lazyload">

Comment: Just to make sure: which TYPO3 version are you using? The data attribute should work with TYPO3 9.5 but I am not sure whether it can be used with older TYPO3 versions.

Comment: My Typo3 version is : 7.6.32

Comment: I am quite sure that the data attribute does not function in TYPO3 7. Sadly the viewhelper reference for TYPO3 disappeared from the internet. Maybe you could succeed in using the additionalAttributes attribute: `<f:image src="path_to_my_default_image" additionalAttributes="{data-src: '{f:uri.image( image: {mediaElement} )}' }" />`